# Clearcase corrupting checked out Project files when changing network connection

Tags: clearcase, ms-project-server-2010

Is anyone aware of a known issue (and workaround) where it seems like Rational ClearCase will corrupt a Microsoft Project file if it is checked out and the network connection changes?  I have a laptop that is docked and hardwired to local network most of the time, and I perform some work with the Project file, then I will undock the laptop to go to a meeting or home for the evening, and upon re-docking, the Project file can no longer be opened and appears corrupt.

The error message shown is "Project cannot open the file.  -Check that the file name and path are correct.  -Check that the file format is recognized by Project..."

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything directly related to [Microsoft Project Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/project/enterprise-project-portfolio-management-project-server-FX103802061.aspx) regarding ClearCase on ibm.com.

I have seen issues with dynamic views, when the view server is on the network (and said network is abruptly cut).
If this is your case, I would recommend using snapshot views.

You can have similar issue with ClearTeam 8.x web views (since the latest versions support dynamic views)

Regarding snapshot views (meaning files directly on your hard drive), you only need to watch for concurrent processes that might still access your file when undocking. A program like **[procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)** can help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think having it be a dynamic view is probably at least part of the root cause.  I restarted the pc and was able to open the file again without any error, so perhaps the pathing to CC server is getting mixed up when switching back/forth from different network access points.

Comment: @AdamSchneider yes, it is possible a process still keep an handle to a file/resource with the wrong path.